# How Do I Turn My Mic Off Ingame?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I just got Plants Versus Zombie Garden Warfare for the PC and absolutely love it accept for one thing, your microphone is turned on by default so every one can hear you!  I searched the settings for a way to turn this off but there is nothing.  I know you can mute other players but that doesn't turn my microphone off.  I  want to know if there is a way to stop everyone being able to hear me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just guessing since it's an Xbox port, but there is no in-game way. You'd have to use Windows to mute your mic. Many PC games don't have internal ways of muting now that I think about it, both the Hardware and Windows usually handle it.

Comment: Does Origin have a platform-wide mic setting? Steam has a voice chat setting for Steamworks games.

Comment: Not sure I will have to check

Comment: You can always use a microphone with a mute button and/or use press to talk.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?!  My headset has a mute button on it!  I am such an idiot.  Feel free to put that as an answer now @Ramhound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you default recording device in windows to something else another device that is completely different do your microphone, then if you still want to use skype or teamspeak you can assign a different microphone in their settings.

I have this as standard just for those kind of games. Normally the developer will patch this because they will get a lot of complaints from the community